# How to get all list using SPContentType

Tags: development, content-type, getlist

I have created WebPart in which I'm getting list item.

I'm passing list name manually.
Now I'm trying to get all list which are associated with SPContentType.
I have created custom SPContentType with name "Birthday".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SPList.ContentTypes` property to check if it contains your custom content type "Birthday" and apply your business logic to that list

**An example from MSDN:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypecollection.bestmatch.aspx

```
    using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace Test
{
   class ConsoleApp
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
         {
            using (SPWeb webSite = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {
               // Get a content type id to search for.
               SPContentTypeId contentTypeId = SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Task;

               foreach (SPList list in webSite.Lists)
               {
                 if (ListContains(list, contentTypeId))
                    Console.WriteLine("The {0} list uses the content type.", 
                                       list.Title);
               }
            }
         }
         Console.Write("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
         Console.ReadLine();
      }

      static bool ListContains(SPList list, SPContentTypeId id)
      {
         SPContentTypeId matchId = list.ContentTypes.BestMatch(id);
         return matchId.IsChildOf(id);
      }
   }
}
```